# Python - Label won't hide when using get_forget()

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to learn how to show and hide widgets when certain fields are selected, I found some code on here however i'm having a little trouble getting it to work how i'd like so wondering if I am missing something.

I am trying to get it so when the 1st radio button is selected one label appears but when the other is selected the first label disappears but the second label appears, and the other way around.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

class NewSoftware:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        lab1 = ttk.Label(master, text = "Hello", font = ("Calibri" ,10))
        lab1.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
        
    def combo_input(self):
        print ("do something")
        
class UpdateSoftware:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        lab2 = ttk.Label(master, text = "Bye", font = ("Calibri" ,10))
        lab2.grid(column = 2, row = 2)
        
    def combo_input(self):
        print ("do something")
        
#Show / hide
def print_selection():
        if var.get() == 1:
            print ("add new software")
            NewSoftware(frame1)

            try:
                lab2.grid_forget()
            except:
                pass;
                
        if var.get() == 2:
            print ("update software")
            UpdateSoftware(frame1)
            try:
                lab1.grid_forget()
            except:
                pass;


#--- GUI ---
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('490x410')
root.title("Software")

var = tk.IntVar()
 
TAB_CONTROL = ttk.Notebook(root)

#--- TAB 1 ---
TAB1 = ttk.Frame(TAB_CONTROL)
TAB_CONTROL.add(TAB1, text = 'Add/Update Software')

frame1 = Frame(TAB1)
frame1.pack(fill='both')

lab1 = Label(frame1, text = "Add/Update Software", font = ("Calibri" ,10))
lab1.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

c1 = Radiobutton(frame1, text='Add New Software',variable=var, value=1, command = print_selection)
c1.grid(column =1, row = 1, sticky = 'W')

c2 = tk.Radiobutton(frame1, text='Update Software',variable=var, value=2, command = print_selection)
c2.grid(column =2, row = 1, sticky = 'W')


#--- TAB 2 ---
TAB2 = ttk.Frame(TAB_CONTROL)
TAB_CONTROL.add(TAB2, text = 'Past Version Checker')
TAB_CONTROL.pack(expand = 0, fill = "both")

frame2 = Frame(TAB2)
frame2.pack(fill='both')

lab1 = Label(frame2, text = "Past Version Checker", font = ("Calibri" ,11 ,"bold"))
lab1.grid(column = 1, row = 0)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: first of you should provide a [mre], second don't use a bare `except` clause, either except an error you expect or do at least `except Exception as e: print(e)` so that you know what exception happened, also don't import `tkinter` twice, remove the last import and adjust code accordingly and now looking more at your code I suggest you take a look at some beginner tutorials on OOP and remove those `try/except`

Comment: also look up what are scopes (and don't use a plain `except` and in your case they are not needed at all, they just hide the error you have (related to scopes))

Comment: You use `lab1` for two different labels, but it can only represent one.